# Scanning serial numbers into Excel's find and replace

Tags: excel, ms-office

We use handheld scanners to scan serial numbers of desktops/monitors for work. Part of the job requires us to scan serials into Excel's find and replace and look at certain information for a specific serial. Generally I would Ctrl+F, scan the serial, look at the line item and then have to manually delete the find and replace field before scanning the next serial. This becomes very tedious after a few hundred. Is there any way to have the next scan overwrite the find and replace field instead of appending to it? Would it be a simple macro or is there just a setting? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: it Would be a simple macro

Comment: tried `=substitute(<YouOldText>,<serials>,<replacementValues>)` ?

Comment: Are you using "find and replace" just to find items, or are you actually replacing things?

Comment: Using the find and replace just to find, looking at information next to the found item, then scanning the next

Comment: In that case maybe consider using a userform (which you can display modelessly) with a textbox to scan into.  When the textbox detects an entry it can trigger code to run a Find() usinf the scanned barcode.